# When does Shirayuki return to Tamburum in the manga?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

When does Shirayuki return to Tamburum after receiving an invitation from Prince Raj in the manga (which chapter)? You see, I kinda lost where I was in the manga and can't seem to find where I was reading. If you could tell, me that would be a big help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That arc starts in chapter 18, the actual invitation from prince Raji is in chapter 19 and shirayuki actually returning to Tamburum is in chapter 20.